# Is it wrong to support a couple who are gays and not Muslims?

Tags: non-muslim, homosexuality

I'm not gay or anything but I know a couple who are and they both are not Muslims and I actually like love their relationship and encourage them,so is that wrong and am I going to be punished ??

Answer (score 4):

As salamu alaikum,

According to Islamic principle related to haram, it is that if something is prohibited, then anything that leads to it is also considered haram. A similar principle is that

`the sin of haram is not limited to the person who engages in the prohibited activity, but the sin also extends to others who support the person in the activity, whether it be material or moral support.`

-Al-Qardawi, Yusuf (1999). 
*The Lawful and the Prohibited in Islam. American Trust Publications. p. 22*

You can find the link to the book [here](http://thequranblog.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/the-lawful-and-the-prohibited-in-islam.pdf).

So, a person who commits a sin, and a person who encourages a sin, both are accountable. Hope, it clarifies what you asked.

Jazakallahu Khair

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but is it prohibited for everyone, or just Muslims?

Comment: Islam is for everyone, and not only for Muslims. So now you can deduce the answer :)

Comment: Yeah, that was a stupid question.

Answer (score -1):

Homosexuality is a sin, and encouraging a sin is also a sin, both are accountable.